# Android studio can't find JNI method but works fine

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I am trying to build a Android program which uses JNI, here's my `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TESSERACT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/tesseract/src
LEPTONICA_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/leptonica/src
LIBJPEG_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libjpeg
LIBPNG_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng

# Just build the Android.mk files in the subdirs
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

`Application.mk`

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
APP_OPTIM := release
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

But Android Studio warns me that **`Java native method can't resolve corresponding JNI method`**, but everyting actually works, the program can compile and run correclty:

[image]

Here's my gradle build script:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
        def ndkDirProperty = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
        def ndkDirPrefix = ndkDirProperty != null ? ndkDirProperty + '/' : ''

        def ndkBuildExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? ".cmd" : ""

        commandLine "${ndkDirPrefix}ndk-build${ndkBuildExt}", '-C', file('.').absolutePath,
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    // Cleanup task to remove previously generated binaries
    task ndkClean(type: Exec) {
        def ndkDirProperty = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
        def ndkDirPrefix = ndkDirProperty != null ? ndkDirProperty + '/' : ''

        def ndkBuildExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? ".cmd" : ""

        commandLine "${ndkDirPrefix}ndk-build${ndkBuildExt}", '-C', file('.').absolutePath, 'clean'
    }

    tasks.withType(Delete) {
        cleanTask -> cleanTask.dependsOn ndkClean
    }
```

Comment: It warns you how?

Comment: @EJP `Java native method can't resolve corresponding JNI method`, seems to be an Android Studio bug ?

Comment: Click to Refresh Linked C++ Projects in Build menu. I had the same problem when i updated to ndk-14. When i downgraded ndk version, everything worked well.